# pip_install ignored when combined with py_image?

Tags: python, docker, pip, bazel

I'm trying to build a "hello, world" Docker image with a depdency specified in requirements.txt. Consider the following files:

## WORKSPACE

```
workspace(name = "bazel01_helloworld")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_docker",
    sha256 = "92779d3445e7bdc79b961030b996cb0c91820ade7ffa7edca69273f404b085d5",
    strip_prefix = "rules_docker-0.20.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/releases/download/v0.20.0/rules_docker-v0.20.0.tar.gz"],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//toolchains/docker:toolchain.bzl",
    docker_toolchain_configure="toolchain_configure"
)

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//repositories:repositories.bzl",
    container_repositories = "repositories",
)

container_repositories()

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//python:image.bzl",
    _py_image_repos = "repositories",
)

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_install")

pip_install(
   name = "my_deps",
   requirements = "requirements.txt",
)

_py_image_repos()
```

## BUILD

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//python:image.bzl", "py_image")
py_image(
    name = "helloWorld",
    srcs = ["helloWorld.py"],
    main = "helloWorld.py",
)
```

## requirements.txt

```
flask
```

## helloWorld.py

```
import flask
print('Hello, world!')
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
> sudo bazel run helloWorld
INFO: Analyzed target //:helloWorld (87 packages loaded, 7245 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:helloWorld up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/helloWorld-layer.tar
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.390s, Critical Path: 2.41s
INFO: 58 processes: 20 internal, 38 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 58 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 58 total actions
Loaded image ID: sha256:370d944e74b0d70ff857130e877235fb921b2b9e3cb4038ac88fe119d8843380
Tagging 370d944e74b0d70ff857130e877235fb921b2b9e3cb4038ac88fe119d8843380 as bazel:helloWorld
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app//helloWorld.binary.runfiles/bazel01_helloworld/helloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Flask is clearly not installed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Once again, I got an answer from user `matt` through #getstarted channel on Bazel Slack:

> There's no reference to the pip dependencies in the py_image target
> https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#py_image

Here's a working example:

## WORKSPACE

```
workspace(name = "bazel01_helloworld")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    sha256 = "954aa89b491be4a083304a2cb838019c8b8c3720a7abb9c4cb81ac7a24230cea",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.4.0/rules_python-0.4.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.4.0/rules_python-0.4.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_docker",
    sha256 = "92779d3445e7bdc79b961030b996cb0c91820ade7ffa7edca69273f404b085d5",
    strip_prefix = "rules_docker-0.20.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/releases/download/v0.20.0/rules_docker-v0.20.0.tar.gz"],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//toolchains/docker:toolchain.bzl",
    docker_toolchain_configure="toolchain_configure"
)

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//repositories:repositories.bzl",
    container_repositories = "repositories",
)

container_repositories()

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//python3:image.bzl",
    _py_image_repos = "repositories",
)

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")

# Create a central repo that knows about the dependencies needed from
# requirements_lock.txt.
pip_parse(
   name = "my_deps",
   requirements_lock = "requirements.txt",
)


# Load the starlark macro which will define your dependencies.
load("@my_deps//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")
# Call it to define repos for your requirements.
install_deps()

_py_image_repos()
```

## BUILD

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//python3:image.bzl", "py3_image")
load("@my_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
py3_image(
    deps = [requirement("flask")],
    name = "helloWorld",
    srcs = ["helloWorld.py"],
    main = "helloWorld.py",
)
```

## external/requirements.txt

```
click==8.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

## helloWorld.py

```
import flask
print('Hello, world!')
```